# Impact of parameters in experimental results of paper

Tags: computer-science, experiment-design

I am writing a paper in computer science literature. I have a method that has two main parameters. It turns out that one of these parameters does not have a significant impact on the quality of the results, but it has a big impact on the efficiency of the method. I have a question:

- How should I explain this in my experimental results section? Should I draw some plots and show that for different variation of this parameter the result is the same (this seems numb to draw some plots that all overlap) or I should write a paragraph and explain this phenomenon?

Comment: This is, afaik, known as sensitivity analysis. Surely, other papers before have had to deal with the issue of how to present the fact that the model *isn't* sensitive to a specific parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I had a programming part in my masters thesis in which I wanted to show that some parameters do not have significant impact on the results. This is what I did which seems to be a combination of your methods:

I drew a plot with all the parameter remaining the same except one parameter that I want to study on. Even if the variation of the parameter does not show any significant change in the results, it does worth to show the results in a plot. It is not important that all the lines overlap. At least the reader sees that the results are the same. But, in a paragraph or at least one sentence following the graph I would talk about this. You may write that all the plots overlap, because of this and because of that; and talk about why such results happen. Also, in the caption of the plot, write something that directly says something about such insignificance.

Comment: I absolutely agree.  I love seeing plots with a whole bunch of overlapping flat lines that essentially say "We hit our method with all sorts of hammers, and it didn't budge!"